# Return list to ajax call from controller asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to return list from my controller to the success function in an AJAX call. I’m able to return the list successfully from controller but inside AJAX call, the code for error gets executed and I get an internal server error.
I searched for the same everywhere, but I’m unable to find a reason why this is happening.

**Following is my AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: "/BookUtility/GetHallsList",
        success: function (hallsList) {
            console.log(hallsList);
        },
        error: function (xhr,status, exception) {
            console.log("Error: " + exception + ", Status: " + status);
        }
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
 Hall objHall = new Hall();
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult GetHallsList()
    {
        var hallsList = objHall.GetHallsList();
        return Json(hallsList.ToList());
    }
```

**`Hall.cs`:**

```
public List<tblHall> GetHallsList()
        {
            List<tblHall> hallsList;
            using (BookingSystemDBEntities db = new BookingSystemDBEntities())
            {
                hallsList = db.tblHalls.ToList();
            }
            return hallsList;
        }
```

I’ve also tried using `List<tblHall> hallsList = objHall.GetHallsList();` in my controller in place of `var hallsList = objHall.GetHallsList();`, but that doesn’t work too.

This is the error I’m getting:
[Error I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbAsj.png)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why do you instantiate  Hall objHall = new Hall(); ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Hall.cs is a model class from where I'm getting list of halls.

Comment: try to instantiate it insdie the method

Comment: It didn't work either.

Comment: is your API working when you invoke from postman?

Comment: Actually, this is an mvc controller. I need to use ajax here to display some checkboxes for the list returned.

Comment: ok i dont see anywhere you are sending data in the http post

Comment: I've tried that too though I didn't require any data here, but it didn't work either.

Comment: can you check if there is an error on chrome developer tools on the request and response, make sure data is returned

Comment: I've now added the snapshot in the question for the same.

Comment: check the response in the same tab, you should see the actual error. or debug the controller

Comment: I tried, but there is no  other error. I think I'm going wrong with something in my controller.

Comment: Okay, If that would help me out.

Comment: share your id sajeetharan@outlook.com

Comment: Hey Did you try to debug your code by putting break point in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error says, the problem is with the web api method. It should throw the error . The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. You can fix it by setting

```
using (var contex = new BookingSystemDBEntities())
{
   context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   hallsList = db.tblHalls.ToList();
}
```